# Ember JS transition to nested routes where all routes are dynamic segments from a view

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-router, nested-routes

We are writing an application using EmberJS. However we are still new with this framework and we're having a hard time resolving some of what may seem to be straight forward.

The model is pretty simple, there are 3 models: Queue, Task, and Image. We are using dynamic URI segments for all routes and routes for these models are nested in the form: **:queue_id/:task_id/:image_id.**

The routes are configured this way:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource('queue', {path: ':queue_id'}, function() {
      this.resource('task', {path: ':task_id'}, function() {
         this.resource('image', {path: ':image_id'});
      });
   });
}
```

And somewhere in the HTML, we have this simple template to iterate through all images from a task:

```
{{#each task.images}}
   <li>
      {{#view App.ThumbnailView.contentBinding="this"}}
         <img {{bindAttr src="thumbnail.url"}} />
      {{/view}}
   </li>
{{/each}}
```

And here is the code for the Thumbnail View:

```
App.ThumbnailView = Ember.View.extend({
   tagName : 'a',
   click : function(e) {
       var task = //assume this value exists;
       var queue = //assume this value exists;
       var image = //assume this value exists;

       this.get('controller.target.router').transitionTo('image', queue, task, image);
   }
});
```

Finally, here's is our ImageRoute:

```
App.Image = Ember.Object.extend();
App.Image.reopenClass({
    find : function(image_id) {
       //This is where I set a breakpoint
       console.log(image_id);
    }
});

App.ImageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(params) {
      //image_id is the last uri segment in: #/1/1/1
      return App.Image.find(params.image_id);
    }
});
```

**The Problem:**
The call to `this.get('controller.target.router').transitionTo()` seems to be working. I can see that when I click in one of the thumbnails view, the URL changes (e.g from /1/1/2 to something like /1/1/3). However, I'm not seeing any state change in the UI. Also, the line where I put a breakpoint doesn't seem to be triggered. But when I refresh the page, it works well.

Is there something wrong with my transition code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two things to note:

First, instead of

```
this.get('controller.target.router').transitionTo('image', queue, task, image);
```

Use:

```
this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('image.index', queue, task, image);
```

This might not change the behaviour, but it's more Ember idiomatic.

The second thing is the following:

Internal transitions will not trigger the `model` hook on the route, because Ember assumes you are passing the model along with the transition, so no need to call the `model` hook since you already passed the model.

That is why your breakpoint doesn't get triggered, the `find` isn't being called (as it shouldn't).

I don't have enough information to find your issue but if I were to guess from the fact that a page refresh works and an internal transition doesn't is that there is an inconsistency between the objects passed to `transitionTo` and between what is returned from the `model` hook.

You should pass the exact object to `transitionTo` as the ones that would have been returned by the`model` hook.

If you are doing:

```
this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('image.index', queue, task, image);
```

and it's not working, something is probably wrong with either `queue`, `task`, or `image` models you are passing.

So this:

```
   var task = //assume this value exists;
   var queue = //assume this value exists;
   var image = //assume this value exists;
```

is not very helpful because it could be where the problem is.

Comment: Hi Teddy. Thanks. You are right, the model returned from the model hook is not the same as the models i am passing. Is there a way I can get the model of the ImageRoute from the ThumbnaiView?

Comment: You don't need to call the actual ImageRoute `model` hook, you need to pass the same model **as if** it was returned from the model hook. You're looping over `task.images`, isn't this an array of `App.Image` model instances (same as you would return from the ImageRoute model hook)?

Comment: Ok thanks. Now I think I know what to do. But since my routes are all by dynamic segments, /queue_id/task_id/image_id, does it mean i need to requery queue and task by their ids then pass those models in the transitionToRoute method? I am thinking if there is a way of getting those models without having to requery. Like for example in any route, I can use the call this.modelFor('routeName') to get the model of that route. In a view I don't think that is possible.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your app here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyzeenny/kZqkx/ hopefully it would give you some idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks Teddy. I'll try this first thing tomorrow morning when I get back to work..