# What controls where Ember's Loading Route is displayed?

Tags: ember.js

I would have thought that the `LoadingRoute` would display its template in the `{{outlet}}` of the main AppView, but it doesn't seem like it does. What determines where it goes?

Here's a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/aloyew/1/) of my problem. The Loading message isn't showing up where I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that you have this mapping:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("foo")
});
```

When is transitioned to `foo` route. It template will be inserted in that was specified in the `into` property of `render` method.
By example:

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
      this.render("foo", { into: "sometemplate" })
    }
});
```

Case this isn't setted, the `foo` route will retrieve the parent route, in that case ApplicationRoute, and insert the template `foo`, into `application` template.
This is the default behavior when you don't override the `renderTemplate` method.

But when no one of that conditions happens, this is the behavior of `LoadingRoute`, because it doesn't have the `ApplicationRoute` as parent. Than ember insert the template in the body tag, or more specifically in `App.rootElement`.

Comment: I didn't understand the hierarchy. I think this best answers my question - thanks!

Comment: In that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476977/ember-js-transition-to-nested-routes-where-all-routes-are-dynamic-segments-from is used a multi level route mapping. This create a kind of hierarchy. The ApplicationRoute is the toppest in the hiearchy and it is the parent for all routes mapped by this.route("myroute"). But at the moment LoadingRoute behaves diferent.

Comment: Thanks! I meant, I didn't understand the hierarchy until you explained it. I get it now :)

Answer (score 5):

Indeed it looks that it is inserted right before the closing tag of the tag with class `ember-application`. You can control to which `outlet` it is inserted using [renderTemplate](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/):

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('loading', {
      outlet: 'loading',
      into: 'application'
    });
  }
});
```

Then place the `loading` outlet wherever you want in the `application` template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <div id="twenty-fifth-cdu-production">

    {{#view App.Sidebar}}
    <div id="left-panel">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    {{/view}}

    <div id="center-panel" class="container-fluid">
      {{outlet}}
      {{outlet "loading"}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Note that the name of the default outlet (i.e., `{{outlet}}`) is `main`. But trying to use the default `outlet` for rendering the `App.LoadingView` creates problems.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/asizim/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you increase the timeout you will be able to notice that `loading` template is attached at the end of document. It is probably designed to be used with overlays of fixed positioned elements.

You can add another `outlet` (called `loading` in example below) and force rendering of `loading` template into it with Route `renderTemplate` hook:

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render("loading", { outlet: 'loading', into: 'application' });
    }
});
```

Check out this example: http://jsbin.com/ipagut/5#/#two

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'connectOutlet' of undefined`. Unfortunately I'm having a hard time reproducing in JsBin. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you created additional, *named* outlet in you application template?

Comment: yes. When I call `this.render('loading'...` I get an error within ember's code saying the parentview is undefined.

Comment: Seemed like the path hadn't changed yet? I wrapped your `this.render` code in a conditional: `if ((this.controllerFor('application').get('currentPath')) {...`. Any idea why that's happening?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this behavior is intentional, so the `LoadingRoute` could work while the `ApplicationRoute` itself is loading. Rendering the application template manually should allow you to render into one of its outlets.

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render("application");
        this.render("loading", { outlet: "loading", into: "application" });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is right. The default is for the loading route to append its template to the body. I think that's where I was confused. In your example, I don't think you need to even call `this.render('application')`.